# Bootstrap Dropdown not working inside Angular ng-repeat

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I think I need a break and cup of tea on this one.

```
<tr ng-repeat="participant in globalData" ng-controller="GlobalDataRowController" ng-class="rowStatus">
    <td>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle">
                Click me for a dropdown, yo!
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="choice in participant.SourceDescriptions">
                    <a>{{choice}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
....
```

I have this code. When the this snippet is placed outside the repeat scope it works fine. But inside the repeat nothing happens when I click.

I'm attempting to use angular-ui but I'd rather not have it just for this job. And I don't think I'm looking at the problem correctly anyway.

Comment: Inspect source and see if multiple li are getting generated.

Comment: No multiple lists are not being generated. But ng-repeat doesn't affect the behaviour of data-list and that isn't repeated in source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking back over previous questions and thought I'd wrap this one up.

I took the approach of using a directive here. It doesn't look perfect but it's doing the job for now. So in the view...

```
<tr ng-repeat="participant in globalData" ng-controller="GlobalDataRowController" ng-class="rowStatus">
  <td>
    <input input-data-list-dropdown id="xx" input-class="input-xxlarge" ng-model="participant.DisplayName" options="participant.SourceDescriptions">
    ...
  </td>
</tr>
```

And the directive...

```
.directive('inputDataListDropdown', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: { options: '=', ngModel: '=', inputClass: '=', id: '=' },
        template: '<span class="dropdown">' +
                      '<a class="dropdown-toggle">'+
                        '<input type="text" class="inputDataListDropdown" ng-transclude ng-model="ngModel">' +
                      '</a>'+
                      '<ul class="dropdown-menu no-bullets" ng-show="options && options.length > 0">' +
                          '<li ng-repeat="option in options">' +
                            '<a ng-click="$parent.ngModel=option">{{option}}</a>' +
                          '</li>'+
                      '</ul>'+
                  '</span>',
        transclude: 'element',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $("#" + attrs.id + " .inputDataListDropdown").addClass(attrs.inputClass);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- a function -->

 $scope.drop_down1 = function () {


        $scope.status = {
            isopen: false
        };

        $scope.toggled = function(open) {
            $log.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
        };

        $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            $scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
        };


    };

<!--create view and use ng-include-->

<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-click="drop_down1()" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>


    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>




<!-- ng-repeat example -->

<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>vm_name</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>restore_type</th>
            <th>state</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in data  | filter:searchFilter | orderBy: 'id' :true">


            <td>{{x.id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.vm_name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.date}}</td>
            <td>{{x.restore_type}}</td>
            <td>{{x.state}}</td>

            <td>

                <div id="ctrl_10_butt" ng-include="'view/view_drop1.html'"></div>

            </td>

   </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some description as to why this answer works, or what was wrong with the original code.